# Menu id in nav menu ignored

Tags: menus

```
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( 
    array( 
        'theme_location' =>'main_menu',
        'container' => false,
        'menu_id'=> 'nav'
    )
); 
?>
```

After updating WordPress to 3.8 menu id is not working. Where is the problem ? 
I like to get menu as

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What markup _are_ you getting? There was no change to this argument in 3.8, it should still work.

Comment: I ma not gating ul id as <ul id="nav">. I have a theme and I used 'menu_id'=> 'nav' to give ul id like <ul id="nav"> but it is not working after updating. I checked by using that function array to add class of menu ul it also not working. I can't understand where is the problem !!

Comment: `<nav id="main_nav">                    
    <ul id="menu-top-menu-1" class="menu DropDownMenu">
        <!-- li items -->
    </ul>
</nav>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `'menu_id'=> 'nav'` by `'items_wrap' => '<ul id="nav">%3$s</ul>'`

Answer (score 0):

The ID might have been omitted by WordPress if you have used it in some other place since no two exact same ID's can exist at the same time.

You should post your output to get more help on that. Is the menu showing but just without the ID or are you getting just `<div></div>` or what?